# Неверно отображается курсор мыши в QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Столкнулся с проблемой в QGraphicsView, при помещении на QGraphicsScene прокси виджета QGraphicsProxyWidget, в котором находится QTableWidget, не всегда верно отображается курсор мыши ресайзе колонок или строк.
Вот небольшой тестовый пример.

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsProxyWidget>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QTableWidget>

MainWindow::MainWindow( QWidget *parent ) :
    QMainWindow( parent ),
    ui( new Ui::MainWindow )
{
    ui->setupUi( this );

    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView ;
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene ;
    scene->setSceneRect( 0, 0, 1000, 1000 );
    QGraphicsProxyWidget *item = new QGraphicsProxyWidget ;
    QTableWidget *table = new QTableWidget ;
    table->setRowCount( 10 );
    table->setColumnCount( 5 );
    table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels( QStringList() << "1" << "2" << "3" << "4" << "5" );
    table->setGeometry( 0, 0, 640, 480 );
    item->setWidget( table );
    scene->addItem( item );
    scene->setFocusItem( item );
    view->setScene( scene );
    setCentralWidget( view );
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Подозреваю что дело в событиях наведения мыши, возможно кто-нибудь решал подобную проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можете скриншот для примера закинуть? не совсем понимаю, что происходит

Comment: Добавил скриншот. Если наводим курсор мыши между колонками или строками, то курсор должен изменяться, но это происходит через раз, однако ресайз колонки или строки все равно можно делать